# Two approvals for new user question edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Currently it takes two approvals from a privileged user to a question's suggested edit (from a new user) for the edit to go into effect. This fails in two ways:

1. Suggested edit approval workflow often keeps a good edit from being approved quickly. Many times questions sit for 10+ minutes before two people click the button and approve which slows down the time it takes for a good answer to roll in and also causes the question to receive downvotes discouraging new users.
2. New users' suggested edits are often just overwritten by the first person that should "Approve" so that the edit will take effect immediately. Then the privileged user shows as the editor even though the work was performed by the new user.

Ultimately, it doesn't make sense to have two approvals since the folks with the privilege to perform the approval already have the privilege to make an edit without needing approval themselves. One person with edit privileges should be allowed to immediately approve a new user's edits. Changing this would solve both issues above.

Certainly this has come up in Meta before, but I'm unable to find a matching question or perhaps this is the wrong forum.

Comment: This is definitely the right site for your question.

Comment: Thank you @cigien That is definitely the same question. I disagree with the answer, but it is hard to argue with "The edit queue clears out quickly" if that is actually true. My experience is that quieter tags can have questions sitting with suggested edits for too long.

Comment: Yes, that's possibly the case. If you feel you can make an argument for this feature, feel free to edit the question. Of course, make sure to read all the arguments, and counter arguments previously made. If you go to the target of the question I linked to, you'll see that there are at least a dozen similar feature requests, and discussions. Take some time to read through those, and if you have something new to add, go ahead and edit this question.

Comment: I appreciate the direction, @cigien. If I get another opportunity to dig, I will definitely add here :)

Comment: "Many times questions sit for 10+ minutes before two people click the button" -- lightning fast compared to the CV queue. I also fail to see the problem - 10 minutes is still fast for suggested edits

Comment: On the other hand, at 20k rep one can single handedly edit tag excepts but they can't be trusted to approve other users' edits?

Comment: Why not just "Improve edit" and make further improvement?

Comment: @IanCampbell I wasn't aware there was a character requirement.

Comment: @IanCampbell If you have edit privileges, I don't believe there's a minimum character change requirement. I've definitely made edits with only single character changes, though they were just edits, as opposed to "improve edit" on a suggested edit. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @cigien I just improved a suggested edit with only one character difference, so it appears I am mistaken. I am not sure if I am just misremembering, it changed with the new review queues, or if something else influences it.

Comment: @IanCampbell I'm afraid I don't know. I don't recall any mention of that changing with the new review queues, though a fair amount of things changed, so that may be one of them. I also don't think it depends on any other factors, but again, I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of having two people review something is a good default because it helps reduce fraud and improves the rate of high-quality edits being approved but low-quality edits being rejected.

However, you *can* approve suggested edits single-handedly by choosing to "Edit and Approve" a suggested edit when opening a suggested edit for review.

When this happens, you do show up as the most recent editor in the revision history, but another entry also shows up in the revision history with the person who suggested the edit initially as the author.

Comment: @IanCampbell My 3rd paragraph points out how that is inaccurate, at least insofar as OP is concerned about a problem.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer. The note about the revision history is what I was missing and I think that helps make the experience for the new user who is making the suggested-edit a better experience. (Assuming it's true. I haven't tested yet).

Comment: @JNevill Here is an example where I unilaterally approved a suggested edit by choosing to "edit" the suggested edit myself: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34662817/revisions. As you can see from the revision history page, my edit revision is shown separately from the suggested editor's revision, including what changes we each made.

Comment: Re *"Edit and Approve""*: I only see the four options *"Approve"*, *"Improve Edit"*, *"Reject and edit"*, and *"Reject"*. Can you clarify?

Comment: @PeterMortensen What, you don't have that privilege unlocked?! Just kidding; couldn't remember what it is called. Improve Edit is the one I'm talking about.